# Ampersands in C++ method Parameters: Diff between SomeType& param1 and SomeType &param1

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here, could someone please let me know the difference between the two following method signatures?

`void AddConcert(const Concert &concert);`

and

`void AddConcert(const Concert& concert);`

Thanks!

Comment: Whitespace generally doesn't matter in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Preference. The compiler treats them the same

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are no difference between them.

We have const Concert& concert, for example, you read it like: reference to a const Concert variable. 
So the second is the same.